# COUNT null values when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm counting the number of votes given to an item, and there's only two possible values:

`vote = 1` and `vote = 2`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM match_votes
WHERE match_id = :match_id 
GROUP BY vote
```

However if there has been no votes for `1` but votes for `2` then it will only return 1 row since it doesn't count null values. I want to return count for `vote = 1` and `vote = 2`, even if there's no votes for the item.

Also, I want to ensure that the count for `vote = 1` is always the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `left join`:

```
select v.vote, count(mv.vote)
from (select 1 as vote union all select 2) v left join
     match_votes mv
     on mv.vote = v.vote
group by v.vote;
```

Or, put the results in two columns:

```
select sum(mv.vote = 1) as vote_1, sum(mv.vote = 2) as vote_2
from match_votes mv;
```

Comment: first query still didn't count the nulls I think, but the second one worked